# How to tokenize a simple mixed string into either ints or symbols?

Tags: ruby, string, tokenize

Trying  to convert a simple math string `"1 2 3 * + 4 5 - /"` to an array of integers and/or symbols like `[1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]`.

Is there a more elegant (and extendable) solution than this?

```
def tokenize s
    arr = s.split(/ /)
    symbols = %w{ + - / * }
    arr.collect! do |c| 
        if symbols.include?(c)
            c.to_sym
        else
            c.to_i
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Why this is not enough? I think it is clear, very easy to read.

Comment: Questions like `Is there a more elegant (and extendable) solution than this?` belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I find your solution more elegant than both of the answers that are currently posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def tokenize(str)
  str.split.map! { |t| t[/\d/] ? t.to_i : t.to_sym }
end
```

Instead of checking if the token is in a set of operations, you can just check if it contains a numeral digit (for your use case). So it's either an integer, or an operation.

Also note that `Array#collect!` and `Array#map!` are identical, and `String#split` by default splits on white space.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
h = Hash[*%w{+ - / *}.map { |x| [x, x.to_sym] }.flatten]
```

And then,

```
arr.map { |c| h[c] || c.to_i }
```

So together:

```
def tokenize s
    h = Hash[*%w{+ - / *}.map { |x| [x, x.to_sym] }.flatten]
    s.split.map { |c| h[c] || c.to_i }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def tokenize s
  s.scan(/(\d+)|(\S+)/)
  .map{|num, sym| num && num.to_i || sym.to_sym}
end
```